# Struggling to get Windows XP to boot after recovering from HDD damage

Tags: hard-drive, boot, windows-xp, partitioning, bios

So I have an old Windows XP machine, and the other day, someone was deleting some files, when the whole system froze up. After a long time, the machine was hard-shutdown by the user. After this, it would not boot, and I determined that the HDD had become corrupted. I removed the HDD from the machine and attached it to my modern laptop with a USB-SATA cable. Since the HDD was RAW, it would not function correctly in windows explorer, however, I managed to salvage what I think is all the data using TestDisk. I then put all of that on another HDD that I had, so I ended up with a file structure that looks like this (See image) in the root of my 'new' NTFS drive. Basically the whole of the Windows XP C:.

Root of the 'new' drive:
[image: Root of the 'new' drive]

However, when I try and boot this drive, I just get a blank black screen with a flashing underscore. OS will not boot.

I am wondering if perhaps the MBR is bad or more likely non-existent since I have changed to a new drive, but I don't specialise in the low level stuff about how an OS boots, so I don't actually have a clue (Hardly even know what an MBR actually is :D)...

I thought perhaps the post here: [How can I fix the MBR after cloning a Windows XP installation?](https://superuser.com/questions/464620/how-can-i-fix-the-mbr-after-cloning-a-windows-xp-installation?newreg=045ca8cf1587415a9ecb75f76b3ab47c) might help, however after booting from a Windows 95 boot CD, I get an A: prompt, but I don't know how to switch to my "C:?" drive to run an `fdisk` on that? Not sure if Win95 even recognizes my HDD.

Any suggestions appreciated as it seems silly that with the entire file system from the old system right there I still cannot boot it.

EDIT/UPDATE:

Thanks for the info. I tried running chkdsk with the HDD attached to another computer, and it completed fairly quickly, with no errors.

I then couldn't really make use of your suggestion to use the Windows XP CD, because this is an old system and the CD, if it ever existed, has long since been lost. Please do let me know if it is possible to download an iso or something and make one...

It then occurred to me that perhaps the partition needs to be marked as active to boot. After making it an active partition, the issue with the flashing underscore was fixed. Silly me.

However, i have now been running into all sorts of other issues, which i have slowly been fixing, mostly by restoring various bits of the registry that have become corrupted/non-existent. At this point i can boot into XP, and login, but everything is very 'glitchy'. Some applications will not load, and parts of the UI seem damaged. Also, when i try to login, i get a dialog box from winlogon which says: Access violation at address 00000000. Write address 00000000. OKing this dialog gets me past it and into Windows, but as i said everything is very buggy.

Would appreciate any suggestions of what to do next, to make this system a bit more functional.

EDIT/UPDATE 2:

Thanks for the MD5. Managed to find an ISO that matched that one, and created a installation CD, and then did a repair installation. This all completed successfully, but after the last reboot, windows booted past the 'welcome screen' (Win XP logo etc), straight to a blank black screen with a functioning mouse cursor. Great. Ctrl + Shift + Esc has not effect, as does Ctrl + Alt + Del. However, if i press Shift 5 times, it does make the sticky keys noise, and the disk activity light flashes occasionally very quickly, however  i cannot get past this...

(I have actually ran the repair installation twice, and rebooted a couple times, however no luck, still the blank black screen + mouse cursor)

Any ideas?

EDIT/UPDATE 3:

I am now very confused. I decided to start afresh, and try and slipstream the appropriate drivers, do a repair install, all in AHCI mode, and see if that works. I re-formatted my HDD, copied all the files from the old HDD onto the 'new old' one, and also created a new, fresh, Windows XP installation disk. (I burned `en_windows_xp_professional_with_service_pack_3_x86_cd_x14-80428.iso` to the CD again, overwriting what was on it). I made sure the BIOS was in IDE mode, just to ensure the installer was at least working as it was before, before continuing. However, despite having everything exactly the same as when i ran the repair installation last time, the installer does not give me an option to run a repair install. If i accept the licence terms, it takes me straight to the menu to select a partition to install Windows to. No repair option. It recognizes the one and only partition, and if i press Enter, it warns me there is already an OS there, and a re-installation will damage it.

Really not sure why it is doing this, when before, when i had everything exactly the same, (unless i have forgotten something silly), it did at least give the option to repair install. If i can get it to give me the option to do a repair install, i will then switch to AHCI, attempt to slipstream the drivers, and do the repair install from there.

Really appreciate your input into this by the way, its very helpful...

EDIT/UPDATE 4:

OK, for some reason, to make the installer detect the broken installation of Windows XP on the HDD, i had to boot into Hiren's Mini XP, and manually restore the SYSTEM, SOFTWARE, SECURITY, SAM, and DEFAULT registry hives from the restore points. (Because they were missing from `C:\Windows\System32\Config`, which is one of the main problems with this system). After this, the installer seemed to give the repair option again. I guess i must have done this the first time around and forgotten...

I then slipstreamed what i hope is the correct AHCI driver into the ISO using nLite, (Seems to be working, no BSOD's on the installer), and set my BIOS to AHCI mode. The repair installer is now running, in AHCI mode, and i am hoping when complete, this time, XP will boot slightly further than a black screen with a mouse cursor. Will report back once it is done.

EDIT/UPDATE 5:

Unfortunately, after the repair installation ran supposedly successfully, the system booted to a nice, black screen with a mouse cursor. Exactly as before. :(

Comment: Honestly, the best course of action is to retire this machine and replace it. If that's not possible, a repair install wouldn't be a bad idea (make a backup before doing this). ISOs can be found online, but they're not made publicly available by Microsoft, so you'll be relying on random people's uploads. Here's an MD5 of a legit file called `en_windows_xp_professional_with_service_pack_3_x86_cd_x14-80428.iso`: `f424a52153e6e5ed4c0d44235cf545d5` (this file was obtained directly from MS)

Comment: Have updated my question in response to your answer.

Comment: Could be a drivers issue. Try safe mode and reinstall the driver. If that's not it, then I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Unfortunately, safe mode does exactly the same thing, just with the "Safe Mode" markings in the corners. However, specifically which drivers were you referring to?

Comment: I thought about the display driver because I thought you have no display output at all. Maybe you could try to access an older restore point if system restore is enabled…

Comment: @gronostaj: I have messed with using restore points a bit (You mean the snapshots of the registry in System Volume Information?), however i have not had much success. I am grasping at straws a bit here, but is it possible that the Windows XP Installation ISO i am using:(`en_windows_xp_professional_with_service_pack_3_x86_cd_x14-80428.iso`), could be the 'wrong one' for my system, and using a different one could help? Or are they all standard? Just seems funny that after doing a REPAIR install it is still encountering a nasty error...

Comment: Also, in case it means anything: A clean install of XP from the ISO works fine, but this is not an option for me due to software installed on the old system that i don't think i can reinstall...

Comment: It could be the wrong one. Unfortunately it's the only English XP ISO that I have in my collection, so I won't be able to provide more MD5s. You could try SP2 or older ISOs. I think you have to match the edition (Home/Pro) too. You'll have to restore the backup from before repair installation before trying again, otherwise it's unlikely to work.

Comment: @gronostajI I may have thought of something that could be causing the issue... The ISO `en_windows_xp_professional_with_service_pack_3_x86_cd_x14-80428.iso` has `x86` in the filename. Does this mean it is for 32-Bit computers, or have i misunderstood? I am thinking if my PC is 64-bit, that could be why this is not working... How can i tell if my PC is 32-Bit or 64-Bit without a functioning OS installed? (From the BIOS?) Only thing is a clean install of Windows XP from this ISO did _seem_ to work alright, so maybe not?

Comment: It means it's the 32-bit version of XP. The 64-bit version was extremely rare and it's very unlikely that you'd have it installed. 32-bit OSes work fine on 64-bit CPUs, they just don't benefit from their 64-bit capabilities.

Comment: Another probably daft comment but i think the original Windows XP was installed and working with the BIOS SATA mode set to AHCI. When running the XP installer from a disc, i first encountered a BSOD, and had to switch to IDE SATA mode to fix it. Could this be affecting anything? (Original installation AHCI, 'repaired' installation trying to be IDE...)

Comment: Maybe. You should rather keep AHCI mode enabled and load the driver like I've described in the answer. XP is quite sensitive about boot device changes.

Comment: @gronostajI Have updated my post as ran out of char's in comment box.

Comment: You may have accidentally enabled some unattended installation option in nLite (or whatever software you used to slipstream the driver).

Answer (score 1):

**Make sure you have a backup of this drive before proceeding. Do not rely on being able to clone the previous drive again.**

Start by running `chkdsk` on the drive on another computer. It may take a couple hours - let it do its thing and wait patiently until it completes.

---

If that doesn't work, you can try to do a repair install from a Windows XP installation disk. It will keep your data and software intact.

You'll need a XP CD that matches your language version and Service Pack. Boot from it.

On some systems in some configurations it's necessary to provide additional SATA drivers as soon as the blue installer screen appears - it's done by pressing <kbd>F2</kbd> or <kbd>F6</kbd> (I don't remember which one it was… It's been a while since I installed XP) and selecting the driver from a floppy which you have to prepare yourself. If floppies are unavailable, the driver can be "slipstreamed" into a custom XP CD with [nLite](https://www.nliteos.com/). If you don't know if this computer will need additional drivers, you can safely proceed without loading them, but you may not be able to select a drive at a later stage.

When the installer finishes loading, **press <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Do *not* press <kbd>R</kbd> for repair yet.**

The installer should detect an existing installation of XP on the drive. Select it for repair and proceed. After a reboot you should be able to access the system.

---

**Finally, prepare a backup strategy.** You may be less lucky the next time something fails.

Comment: Have updated my question in response to your answer.